# is it problem with respect to seo if we add same product to 5 different categories

Tags: seo

I did this : system > configuration > catalog > seo >

Use Categories Path for Product URLs : NO

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products : yes

i added same product to 5 different categories.

we have some 1000 products.

if i follow the same procedure to all 1000 products, it means

if i add all products to 5 different categories, is there any problem related to "SEO"

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" is set to "NO", you should not have any duplicate content issue because all these products with different categories will be pointing to the same product url.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the canonical tag on your pages as well, then you can duplicate but make sure Google knows which is the most important.  This is relevant for translation as well if you are doing internation sites.

Link to docs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en